# Start Webcam App With Systemd On Linux

Tags: linux, systemd, udev

I have a simple application which streams video with a webcam called "streamer". I'd like to start "streamer" when my Linux device boots with systemd.

Next, I have the following systemd, service file, /lib/systemd/system/streamer.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Webcam Service

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/streamer

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I run this manually, it works such as:

```
systemctl start streamer
```

However, when I enable the script and reboot, it does not start automatically:

```
systemctl enable streamer
reboot
```

How can I get this to work with my webcam?

Answer (score 2):

I had to add a udev rule to detect camera, `/etc/udev/rules.d/webcam.rules`:

```
KERNEL=="video0", SYMLINK="video0", TAG+="systemd"
KERNEL=="video1", SYMLINK="video1", TAG+="systemd"
```

Then I made the following changes to my service file, `/lib/systemd/system/streamer.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Webcam Service
BindsTo=dev-video1.device
After=dev-video1.device

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/streamer
```

The reason for this is in the manpage for `systemd.unit`:

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#BindsTo=

> When used in conjunction with `After=` on the same unit the behaviour of `BindsTo=` is even stronger. In this case, the unit bound to strictly has to be in active state for this unit to also be in active state.

```
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```